# Broken layout on Personal Statement

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, design

When using the updated profile page and editing the personal statement, the textarea extends outside of the main column.

[image: Personal statement textarea extends outside the main column]

It looks like the wrapping div that goes around the textarea is missing the "clear" class.

[image: DIV with empty class attribute]

Add that class fixes the problem in the browser(FF) for me.

Comment: Marking this as completed - Jon fixed this on Aug 7.